# emulator and mobile is showing different behavior ,but why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My mobile(android) and PC emulator(from Android Stdio) are showing different result with the same code and also at the same time.

Actually I think , my emulator is running according to my code but my phone is not.

actually the "toast" class makes the difference between them.....

here some small portion of code are given

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId()==R.id.imageTest)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for clicking Image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //this portion not working properly

           //emulator run this portion properly but mobile is not....
        }
        try {

            String str1 = text1.getText().toString();
            String str2 = text2.getText().toString();

            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(str2);

            if (v.getId() == R.id.plus) {
                result.setText("Result: " + (num1 + num2));
            }
            else if (v.getId() == R.id.minus) {
                result.setText("Result: " + (num1 - num2));
            }
            else if (v.getId() == R.id.multiple) {
                result.setText("Result: " + (num1 * num2));
            }
            else if (v.getId() == R.id.divider) {
                result.setText("Result: " + (num1 / num2));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

In this situation what should i do..??
and What is the reason behind it....??

my phone is Samsung A20.
and my emulator phone by android studio is google Pixel2

Comment: Hey @Ankan, not sure what is an actual requirement but in my opinion, you can set a click listener directly to your ImageView. Since this is the generic click listener, it can invoke click from anywhere. According to your code, your Toast would be displayed only when you click on the image but the rest of the code can be triggered from all click registered view.

Comment: debug it by putting breakpoint at your toast and check whether your image click is getting called